# Kentico CMS Version 10

Tags: kentico

I want to run the Checked-out-pages report but there are no parameters.  The only thing I see in the layout is this line of code

%%control:ReportTable?CheckedOutDocsTable%%

I haven't found any tutorials or even reference material to fully explain how to create parameters.    I appreciate any possible help.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on defining report parameters can be found at:

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/working-with-system-reports/defining-report-parameters

The *[View](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/files/62068040/62068041/1/1405944895107/Reporting_Table.png)* tab of the *Checked-out Pages* report should already be populated with a table of checked-out pages, so long as you are using [content locking](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-and-using-page-versioning/content-locking) and at least one page has been checked-out by a user.